# Wrong values trying to get words count from a Microsoft Word document with OpenXML?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, openxml

have a word document and I want to get word count programmatically using OpenXML sdk, 
 I managed to get word count **but openXML returns wrong values. 
note that the test document is mixed languages (Arabic, English) Arabic is RTL language.**

if you open the word document using Microsoft word in the UI it gives you the correct number of words

but if you go and get the value stored in the app.xml file for the same document you will get different value.

I tried the code in this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb521237(v=office.14).aspx

```
// To retrieve the properties of a document part.
public static void GetPropertyFromDocument(string document)
{
    XmlDocument xmlProperties = new XmlDocument();

    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = 
        WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, false))
    {
        ExtendedFilePropertiesPart appPart = wordDoc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart;

        xmlProperties.Load(appPart.GetStream());
    }
    XmlNodeList chars = xmlProperties.GetElementsByTagName("Characters");

    MessageBox.Show("Number of characters in the file = " +
        chars.Item(0).InnerText, "Character Count"); 
}
```

the file I tested contains

word count is 13 but using upper code it gives me 11!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[DocIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio) is a .NET library that can read, write and render Word 2003/2007/2010/2013/2016 files. Using DocIO library of Syncfusion, you can get the correct word count.  The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Step 1: Create a console application
Step 2: Add reference to Syncfusion.DocIO.Base, Syncfusion.Compression.Base and Syncfusion.OfficeChart.Base; You can add these reference to your project using NuGet also.
Step 3: Copy & paste the following code snippet.

This code snippet will produce the words count in the Word document as per your requirement.

```
using Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS;
using Syncfusion.DocIO;
using System.IO;

namespace DocIO_MergeDocument
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //Creates a new Word document
        WordDocument document = new WordDocument(@"InputDocument.docx");
        //Update the words count in the document.
        document.UpdateWordCount(false);
        //Get the updated words count
        int wordCount = document.BuiltinDocumentProperties.WordCount;
        //Releases the resources occupied by WordDocument instance
        document.Dispose();
    }
}    
}
```

For further information about DocIO, please refer our [help documentation](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/overview)

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: Thank you, I will check your free license. since I am individual developer trying to start new business.

Comment: when do you expect to support ast.net core 1.0?

Comment: @TawfiqInjass - ASP.NET Core support is scheduled to be published before the end of June 2016.